# How to use d.ts file for intellisense in VS Code similar to NPM approach

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a nodejs project (in JS). Unfortunately, I have to utilize a lot of node global variables.

Everything works fine (even a lot of people are suggesting not to use globals) except thing:

There is no intellisense for globals. So every time I want to use, let's say, global function/object I need to look in its code and figure out what are the
parameters, what does it return, etc.

Let's say I have a global variable which is a pure object:

```
foo = {
    bar: {
        level2: {
            level3: {
                level4: "abc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's quite annoying to deal with it since I can't "see" the structure of the object when using it and it's easy to make a mistake when writing code.

The reason why I posted this question is the ...npm packages

There are plenty of packages written in vanilla JS and most of them are utilizing the power d.ts files.
Once you install the package you can use it from any place in your projects and VS code will have intellisense for them. If you will click on tooltip (IDK how it's called... Type definition tooltip?) of VS code
you will be navigated to the d.ts file of the package (not the actual implementation of the command).

So my question is how to do the same in my project. I'm not going to publish it as npm I just want a d.ts file somewhere in the project so I can 
use my global without looking into its implementation every time I need to recall what it does.

Comment: I have answered your question check whether it's working for you.

Comment: @Adityatoke thank you I will try it out. You are mentioning the `.ts` files but my project is in JS. They whole point of this question is that I'm trying to figure out how to do the same as what is done many in npm packages: entire code base is in vanilla JS but thanks to one `d.ts` file VS Code can provide you a type tooltips (even it's not a typescript)

Comment: @Adityatoke so before trying it I would like to know is your suggestion suitable for my purpose. I don't even have `tsconfig` or typescript installed. I just want to let VS Code know about my nodejs global vars.

Comment: yes I tried it out with js file also, updated my answer for JS also

Comment: @Adityatoke I have made a demo repo that is very close to my case. I'm having hard time to understand how to apply your solution. https://github.com/anotheruser584/SOquestion .

Comment: ok will look into your repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215740/discussion-between-aditya-toke-and-anotheruser).

Comment: I have added the working of your question in our discussion chat, you can check and confirm

Comment: Hello! Currently I'm having success getting typings in my js files using `/// <reference path="....." />` - but I have many files and want to avoid this appearing in all of them. Did anyone manage to define a path to `.d.ts` files which gets used by all files in the vscode project? E.g. via `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 4):

Let inside your `.d.ts` file be anything

To access variables, functions, interface add this line in your `.ts` file, VS code IntelliSense will suggest you

```
/// <reference path="./test.d.ts" />
```

If you want to use this `test.d.ts` all over your project not just on any particular file. Then add this line in `tsconfig.json`

```
"files" : [ "./src/test.d.ts" ]
```

**Update as mentioned in the comment section**

my js file which I am assuming similar to what you are trying to do

```
export const testString = 'aditya';
```

in  your js file you

```
/// <reference path="test.js" />
```

Comment: @anotheruser I have added the working of your question in our discussion chat, you can check and confirm

Comment: You explanation gave me a solid push in understanding of types usage outside TS. I'm rewarding this answer. However if I will be able to achieve what I'm planing to I will post a separate answer.

Comment: @anotheruser Great to hear that 

Comment: I am using a tool that uses node as a scripting host for scripts written using a special convention (FYI: the tool is a build system and the "scripts" are buildspecs). This tool also provides a .d.ts with a library of functions that can be used in those scripts. But a project that USES the tool doesn't need to be a typescript project (it can be C++ or anything), and there cannot be an assumption that it even HAS a tsconfig.json. How to do this WITHOUT tsconfig.json AND WITHOUT adding <reference> in every buildspec file?

Comment: I have been looking for an answer as to how to get a local .d.ts file to activate the intellisense in VS Code.  The addition of the file through the files property in the jsconfig.json file looks great!  But it does not seem to work in my JS inside an HTML page which are NOT typescript and not modules.  Why is this so hard?  I have been searching for the last two hours.  Here is my json (without compilerOptions and exclude).  The path works the d.ts file works in Atom with TypeScript.

{
    "files" : [  
        "./typescript/zim_ts/typings/zim/index.d.ts"
    ]
  }

Comment: Just looking at the specs for the jsconfig.json at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig and there is no mention of a files property.  Oh!  I see... you have a tsconfig.json file.  Okay... well... from what I understand, VS Code will read the jsconfig.json and it is supposed to be similar to the tsconfig.json.  Still in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of if it is possible or not, the worst drawback of what you are looking for is that the declaration file(s) must be kept updated by hand each time a global variable/function is changed.

> There are plenty of packages written in vanilla JS and most of them are utilizing the power d.ts files.

Usually `.d.ts` files are not written by hand, but are produced by `tsc`: many of the packages you are speaking about are probably written in TypeScript and distributed as JavaScript packages (to be used in JavaScript projects as well) with an associated `index.d.ts` file (to be used in TypeScript projects)

> even a lot of people are suggesting not to use globals

+1